# TypeError:Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'SMTP'

Tags: node.js, express

[image]

I want to use the nodemailer to send email but it trow this error, I reference it from a book *WEB DEVELOPMENT WITH NODE AND EXPRESS*

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this structure as the original one(mailTransport=) has been changed:-

```
smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'Gmail', 
auth: {
xoauth2: xoauth2.createXOAuth2Generator({
user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
//and other stuff here
 });
 }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this gives error:  `ReferenceError: xoauth2 is not defined`

Comment: Simply do: `npm install xoauth2` in terminal and put `const xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');` in your route.js